# Wordpress url rewrite : exception for pages

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a problem with Wordpress permalinks
I use this structure :

```
domain.com/%postname%.htm
```

But i would like to make an exception for pages, i want them to be folders, with a slash at the end, like this :

```
domain.com/my-page/
```

So, i want to have :

```
domain.com/my-page/
domain.com/my-post.htm
```

I have not find any solution for this... someone help ?

Thank you
Guillaume

EDIT :
I tried something with this hook :

```
add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules', 'wp_page_rewrite_rules' );
function wp_page_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_rules )
{
    end( $rewrite_rules );
    $rewrite_rules =  array(
        '(.+?)([0-9]+)?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]'
    );
    return $rewrite_rules;
}
```

But it does not change anything...

Comment: I know this is possible with apache but I'm not sure with WP.

Comment: There is a [page_rewrite_rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_rewrite_rules) hook, but it isn't well documented.

Answer (score 0):

in any case you may use .htaccess file and redirect anything you want to anything.
for simple pages use Redirect 301:

```
Redirect 301 /old_page /new_page
```

for difficult dynamic use RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?pagename=$matches$1 [L,QSA]
```

this are just examples

documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-trailing-slash-fixer/

Thanks everyone, it works well :) (see it works : http://www.divimag.com)